# getChatMembersCount telebot

Tags: python, bots, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

My code:

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot(constants.token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['roll'])
def handle_command(message):
    roll = random.randint(1, 100)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, roll)
    bot.getChatMembersCount()


bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Error:

> AttributeError: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute
>   'getChatMembersCount'

How to use 'getChatMembersCount'?

P. S. I use https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called `get_chat_members_count` ([direct link to implementation](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/telebot/apihelper.py#L206)).

From https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/ :

> **Methods**
>
> All API methods are located in the TeleBot class. They are renamed to follow common Python naming conventions. E.g. getMe is renamed to get_me and sendMessage to send_message.

Answer (score 1):

```
#Send a text from bot to channel by forward
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
    def main(message):
        if message.forward_from_chat:
            apiuz=message.forward_from_chat
            count = bot.get_chat_members_count(apiuz.id)
            bot.send_message(chat_id, count)
```

Comment: add some description